# Installing both snmp and snmp:i386 package on 20.04 (focal) -issue

Tags: apt, 20.04, package-management, 32-bit

Note: this question is not about the default repositories

I need the latest sane package to install, because my scanner is not supported by the main 10.29 libsane included in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. The latest `libsane` package has a dependency on `snmp`. The latest Wine also needs the i386 version of the `libsane` package, but this can not be installed due to the `snmp` dependency.

It looks like only one snmp is allowed.

Task performed:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt update
Hit:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:2 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                      
Hit:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease                 
Hit:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease               
Hit:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease                
Hit:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease
Get:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main Translation-en_GB [485 kB]
Get:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/restricted Translation-en_GB [3.860 B]
Get:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe Translation-en_GB [319 kB]
Get:10 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/multiverse Translation-en_GB [105 kB]
Fetched 913 kB in 3s (357 kB/s)                                        
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up-to-date.
```

This works:

```
sudo apt install snmp
```

This fails:

```
sudo apt install snmp:i386
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 dconf-gsettings-backend : Depends: dconf-service (>= 0.36.0-1)
                           Depends: dconf-service (< 0.36.0-1.1~)
 dictionaries-common : Depends: libtext-iconv-perl but it is not going to be installed
 libcurl3-gnutls : Depends: libssh-4 (>= 0.8.0) but it is not going to be installed
 librdf0 : Depends: libraptor2-0 (>= 2.0.14) but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: librasqal3 (>= 0.9.31) but it is not going to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

I also tried to install from `.deb`. This worked:

```
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/n/net-snmp/snmp_5.8+dfsg-2ubuntu2.3_amd64.deb

sudo dpkg -i snmp_5.8+dfsg-2ubuntu2.3_amd64.deb
```

This also worked:

```
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/n/net-snmp/snmp_5.8+dfsg-2ubuntu2.3_i386.deb

sudo dpkg -i snmp_5.8+dfsg-2ubuntu2.3_i386.deb
```

However, the package remains broken. To fix it, I must perform:

```
apt --fix-broken install
```

This replaces `snmp:i386` with the 64-bit version of `snmp`.

or this maybe a bit clear:

```
sudo apt install -s --no-install-recommends snmp snmp:i386
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
snmp is already the newest version (5.8+dfsg-2ubuntu2.3).
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 snmp : Conflicts: snmp:i386 but 5.8+dfsg-2ubuntu2.3 is to be installed
 snmp:i386 : Conflicts: snmp but 5.8+dfsg-2ubuntu2.3 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Can be this fixed in any way? How can I install both versions of `snmp`?

---

The first 3 commands in the answer ran successfully, then:

```
$ sudo apt-get install snmp:i386

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 dconf-gsettings-backend : Depends: dconf-service (>= 0.36.0-1)
                           Depends: dconf-service (< 0.36.0-1.1~)
 dictionaries-common : Depends: libtext-iconv-perl but it is not going to be installed
 librdf0 : Depends: libraptor2-0 (>= 2.0.14) but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: librasqal3 (>= 0.9.31) but it is not going to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

Comment: Can't reproduce this on fresh 20.04 LTS docker container, so there are problems with repositories.

Comment: @N0rbert: May I know what do you get if you run this: sudo apt install -s --no-install-recommends snmp snmp:i386
Interesting is that on hirsuite there is no problem with this, only on focal

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to restore official default repositories and `ppa-purge` third-party *snmp*-related PPAs from the system.

Then you have to try the following hack:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libsnmp35:i386
sudo apt-get install snmp:i386
```

Also you should know that installation of packages using low-level `dpkg` tool is dangerous, it may break your system.

Comment: does not working, even the first 3 commands were OK. See my answer....